# termination character of string in python

Tags: python, string

is there any termination character like '\0' in C for string in python? we can print the string character by character using the following code in C.

```
while (ch[c] != '\0')
{
   putchar(ch[c]);
   c++;
}
```

Comment: There is no termination character for strings in python. If you want to print each character of string, you can use `while (i < len(str)): print str[i] i+=1`

Comment: @blunderboy `for c in ch: print c`

Comment: @Kiro Thanks!! I just wanted to propose a C-like approach

Answer (score 2):

In python, a string is an object. It comes with attributes and methods. You cannot really compare this to a C `char*` which is basically just a memory address.

You can use the `len(...)` function on a string object to know its length and do whatever you want about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to loop through the string, you can use a for loop.

```
import sys
for c in ch:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
```

but, this works just as well, except it adds a new line

```
print ch
```

This doesn't print a new line (but does add a space)

```
print ch,
```

---

If you need the index, you can do any of the above, but in an enumerated fashion.

```
for i, c in enumerate(ch):
    print i, c
```

This gives:

```
0 a  
1 b  
2 c  
3 d
```

---

For a more c-like approach, which isn't recommended, you can do this:

```
ch = "abcd"
i = 0
while i < len(ch):
    ch[i]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python string is not nul-terminated.

Why don't you just the string?

```
>>> ch = 'abcd'
>>> print(ch)
abcd
```

Comment: then actually on what basis the string is terminated? is it on the length? will it count at the time of inputting the string?

Comment: python sees a string as an iterable list of characters. when data comes in from outside (ie, using the raw_input command) it's preformatted into a python string object.